# How could a Star Destroyer hover over a city in Rogue One?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

In the *Rogue One* trailer—as well as the actual film itself—we see a Star Destroyer hovering directly over a city on the planet’s surface.

How is it possible?

I thought that all capital ships were built in space, because they were too heavy to lift from the planet’s gravitation after completion.

In the movie, the Star Destroyer hovers over the location for a long time. There are no Repulsorlift that could hold that much weight in the air, so how is that possible?

Comment: Voting to leave open as this is asking about in-universe technology/physics, and I believe it can have an in-universe answer.

Comment: Why do you say "There are no repulsorlifts that could hold that much weight in the air"? The very fact that we see it happening throughout the franchise suggests there are!

Comment: “I thought that all capital ships were built in space, because they were they were too heavy to lift from the planet's gravitation after completion” — *YOU THOUGHT WRONG SUCKA*

Comment: I know there are plenty of legends references to shipyards in space (in legends capitol ships don't enter the atmosphere). I can't think of any in the new cannon.

Comment: As worded, your question is inherently flawed. "There are no Repulsorlift that could hold that much weight in the air, so how is that possible?" Well, there clearly are repulsorlifts that can hold that much weight in the air. It's right there on screen.

Comment: I remember ships lifting from the ground of Coruscant in Episode 2. you could think of those ships as predecessors to Star Destroyers. So, even though you would build those ships in orbit, they seem to be capable to operate in a planet's atmosphere.

Comment: "How"? With great effort.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From the [*Battlefront: Twilight Company*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battlefront:_Twilight_Company) novel, which is part of new canon:

> "We're in atmosphere," [the Star Destroyer captain] said, embarrassed at his own urgent tone. "We need full power to stay aloft. Any disruption at all - " Star Destroyers were extraordinary vessels, capable of razing mountains and carrying armies. But their mass was measured in millions upon millions of tonnes, and their energy requirements were vast.
>
> <sup>*Battlefront: Twilight Company* Chapter 38</sup>

It implies that Star Destroyers are perfectly capable of operating within atmospheres, it just draws a significant amount of power (presumably repulsorlift technology is used to keep aloft, though there may also be ventral thrusters). This is supported by numerous depictions of Star Destroyers operating within atmospheres in Rebels, and *Star Wars: Attack of the Clones Incredible Cross-Sections* (which is Legends) noting that the massive Lucrehulk core ships use repulsorlift technology to land.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I added the quote from the novel

Comment: It's worth noting as well that Episode II and III had Acclamators and Venerators landing on Coruscant.

Comment: There are also a handful of instances in the clone wars animated series (Not sure if it's canon) where we see star destroyers happily landed on planets offloading clone troopers.

Comment: Clone Wars is canon.

Answer (score 12):

This image, from Star Wars Rebels:

[image]

Rebels is canon, so therefore Star Destroyers are quite capable of operating in a planet's atmosphere.

Comment: This doesn't explain *how* it is capable.

Comment: magic from the galaxy far, far away! or if you arent satisfied with that answer... Jar-Jar did it!

Comment: Star Destroyers do not even have landing gear so they are not primarily created for this purpose. I'm waiting for an answer in the lines of: _"Every capital ship can operate in the atmosphere but they are being built in the space, because this and this..."_ or _"Only smaller Star Destroyers are specifically designed to be able to hover over planet"_, or _"Jabha was a moon so it has lower gravity"_ or anything that would plausibly (and hopefully canonically) explain **how** do they operate on the planet surface.

Answer (score 3):

It may be a Victory Class. The Victory Class was an early Star Destroyer class that could operate in planetary atmospheres. They were also considerably smaller than the Imperial Class Star Destroyer being only 900 meters long. There were two versions of this class, the Victory I and Victory II.

Sources
http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Victory_I-class_Star_Destroyer
http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Victory_II-class_Star_Destroyer

Comment: Looking at an image of the Rogue One Star Destroyer, it's definitely not a Victory-class unless they look completely different in new canon (so far they have only had a mention).

Comment: Wookieepedia says it's an Imperial I class, which they give an atmospheric speed for.   http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedha_City